# Django custom user profile is only showing for superuser

Tags: django-admin

I added a custom ManyToMany field to my user profiles.  It works fine and displays in the admin pages if I'm logged in as a superuser, but otherwise, it does not show in the admin pages.

```
#models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    things = models.ManyToManyField(Thing)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

#admin.py
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1
    filter_horizontal = ('things',)

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfileInline,]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why does the custom field only show up for superusers instead of for everyone with access to the admin site (staff members)?

Comment: I guess only they have the privilege to see that. Can you check the rules applicable to your custom field?

Comment: Doh - now I see.  That was the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, then I answer your question, so we can close this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a privilege problem, the rules applicable to your custom field are the cause of this behavior. You should check the rules applicable to the custom field.

Comment: To be clear for others - all I did was go to the admin site and add the permission 'Can change user profile' for the group I wanted.